# Fixed error in Liferay IDE, but the red mark does not disappear

Tags: eclipse, liferay-ide

I had made an error in Liferay IDE.
I fixed it but the error still shows up, even after cleaning the project and restarting Liferay IDE:

[image]

How to refresh for real to rid of the error status?

## Full details

I generated some entities using Liferay's Service Builder, in particular a `getName()` method got generated (with zero argument). I started writing a JSP using these entities. At first I wrote `getName(locale)`, but then I remembered that the method takes no arguments so I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning and restarting Liferay IDE a second time did the trick.